# Compiling Cling with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cling

I am trying to build cling for Windows using Visual Studio. After all the steps were completed as shown below, I don't seem to have the cling.exe in the directory /cling/build/Debug/bin for some reason. There's a clang.exe, clang++.exe and a bunch of random llvm ones but it seems that only cling.exe is missing. Does anyone know if I am missing some steps or what went wrong?

// Install CMake 3.6.0 and Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows desktop

git clone root.cern.ch/git/llvm.git src

cd src

git checkout cling-patches

cd tools

git clone root.cern.ch/git/cling.git

git clone root.cern.ch/git/clang.git

cd clang

git checkout cling-patches

cd ../..

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=[Install Path] ..\src -G "Visual Studio 14"

//Go inside build directory and open LLVM.sln, run "Build Solution" on "Debug" and "Win32"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it doesn't work for Windows currently but it will be ready in a couple of week.
https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=22006&sid=b9bc976106f30bdd02d48427a88aa04e